# ROS driver for Lightware SF-40/C laser scanner

Tags: ros, laser, driver, scanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone written a ROS driver for the [Lightware SF-40/C laser scanner](http://www.lightware.co.za/shop/en/products/45-sf40c-100-m.html)
I found one for [SF-10/C altimeter](http://www.lightware.co.za/shop/en/drone-altimeters/33-sf10a.html) here https://github.com/wavelab/ros_lightware. Not sure if this will work for SF-40/C as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226362/ros-driver-for-lightware-sf-40/c-laser-scanner/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks probable, we don't have one to test, but the interface looks the same.

---

Originally posted by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) with karma: 31 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2016-02-11**:
Thanks for the quick help! I ll test soon and get back to you.

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2016-02-14**:
rosrun altitude_sensor altitude_sensor_node

INFO 1455503400.766892744: The serial port is opened. ERROR 1455503401.768272992: Timeout!

ERROR 1455503402.769572975: Timeout!

[ERROR] [1455503402.769572975]: Timeout!
^Cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'cereal::Exception'
what():  po

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2016-02-14**:
^Cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'cereal::Exception'

what():  poll failed -- error = 4: Interrupted system call (in cereal::CerealPort::readBytes)

Aborted (core dumped)

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2016-02-14**:
Able to read the data via [minicom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom).
Also the lightware terminal doesn't work with Wine on Ubuntu. Did you happen to try it?

**Comment by [stevenwaslander](https://answers.ros.org/users/20407/stevenwaslander/) on 2016-02-15**:
The code works by reading a fixed number of bytes, and is not receiving those bytes.  You may need to set it to streaming mode first.  Did not try lightware terminal in Wine.  This is a pretty basic driver, shouldn't take too long to figure out the differences.